# ill with/from cold

Tags: word-choice

I have come across few sentences and was confused to choose correct one.

- He was suffering with cold
- He was suffering from cold.
- He was ill with cold
- He was ill from cold

  Here cold implies viral disease.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it depends whether you mean *the common cold*, which is an infectious disease, or *low temperature*.

> **He is suffering from a cold** 
>   and 
>   **He is ill with a cold**

are both correct, and mean "he has contracted the disease".

> **He is suffering from cold**

(without the article before *cold*) is also correct, but this means the air temperature (or perhaps his body temperature) is dangerously low, perhaps freezing or below.

> **He is ill with cold**

is not wrong, and means the same thing (to do with the air or body temperature). However, this would be an unusual phrase in Standard English.

Comment: If your body temperature gets too low you might be *suffering from hypothermia*.